# DNS issues, flushing helps sometimes

Tags: windows-10, dns

Been struggling with this on my laptop for a while now, and it just gets more and more annoying. When browsing, I frequently get the following:

> This site can’t be reached
>   www.facebook.com’s server IP address could not be found.
>   Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
>   DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Windows Network Diagnostics tells me that "The DNS server isn’t responding". I've tried different DNS servers and getting DNS server automatically, but it doesn't make a difference. "ipconfig /flushdns" in cmd sometimes helps, sometimes doesn't. I have the same problem on all networks, and non-browser apps such as Skype and Whatsapp have no connection issues. I've tried all kinds of fixes I've found online but nothing seems to work. Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Properties should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEvqz.png)

Once I have been through the same. And the reason this was happening was not that of Windows.

It is due to the Proxy Server in my case. So I'd suggest you check the VPN settings in your windows. I think you must have downloaded something that contained a virus and setting a VPN for you which is why you're not able to access DNS.